# How to customize footnote in tables for PDF

Tags: dita-ot

DITA Experts

In my dita, there servaral table who has fn insides.

I wish to create fn for each table 
   1.   fn number starts from 1 for each tabel
   2.   fn list is under its table, not at the bottom of a pages.

What I have done:

1. rewrite topic/fn template make is only shows fn number in table, but not fn contents in page.

   2. rewrite topic/table, wish to touch the fn in table and show its related contents. but now, can't touch it. 
      blow are code which I want to touch for test.

      ```
      <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="table">  


        <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="contains(@class, ' topic/fn ')">
               <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:otherwise>

                   </xsl:choose>       

        </fo:block>
      ```

Would any of you share any clue for me where to start.

Thanks a lot